# why is @Html.ActionLink opening new tab?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the mvc 5 template that comes with a new mvc application.

The existing code has the following:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

Which correctly renders as:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

But when I click them (and all the other links which are the same) a new tab is being opened up.

There is no target="_blank", why is this happening? Am i Just missing something really daft or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if you have `<base target="_blank">`, or if you're holding down Control.

Comment: Ahhh <base href="@Url.Content("~/")" id="basetag" target="_blank">